# React issues with jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm having some issues using react.
When I'm trying to write something like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Navbar() {
    <>
    nav.navbar
    </>;
}
```

I cant seem to get the jsx typing to work
What am I missing? normally this should have turned into:

```
<nav className=navbar></nav>
```

but its not doing anything.

Can anyone help me with this?

I tried installing some extensions that should support it, reinstall node and stuff

Comment: Please provide more details, what exactly are you trying to do? 
Are you trying to use emmet?  
Or you are trying to inject JSX expression? 

And you forgot to add return, react components should return the markup

Comment: Did you mean to use `{nav.navbar}` ? If not, what do you mean by "jsx typing", and "its not doing anything", and how did you get from your code to `<nav className...>`? Where did `className` come from? Are you asking about auto-text expansion in your editor, like using Emmet? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: The issues are related to `syntax errors` on your end. I don't think it is appropriate for StackOverflow to be used for something that can be fixed by simply reading the output of the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Visual Studio Code, go to *Settings* and search for **emmet**.

In the results, you will find a tab that reads:

> Emmet: **Include Languages**
> Enable Emmet abbreviations in languages that are not supported by default. Add a mapping here between the language and Emmet supported language. For example: `{"vue-html": "html", "javascript": "javascriptreact"}`

There, you should add in the list the items from the description above, as such:

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| javascript | javascriptreact |
| vue-html | html |

You can also achieve this by editing your `settings.json` file directly and adding this:

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "vue-html": "html",
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it will not automatically show. You are confusing it with emmet. That will show in editor if you are using emmet. Otherwise you have to write it. Update the code like this:-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <>
           <nav classname="navbar"></nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: This is still incorrect. You're missing the return, the semicolon does not go there for the fragment, and an export if it's going to be used in another file.

Comment: I was just giving example. didn't notice that. Thank you

Comment: I understand that, but you still want to give a correct example. I was pointing it out so you also knew, good job fixing it quickly. For OP, if this component is going to be used somewhere else as `<Navbar />`, `export default Navbar` should be added to the end of the file.

Comment: @DrZoo Sure, that's why I updated the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a tool called Emmet, this allows you to enter abbreviations which are then auto expanded to the desired code.

As it is not working it would seem that Emmet is either not installed, or not configured for you code editor.

You will need to download, install and configure it before the abbreviations will work.

You haven't mentioned which editor you are using so the best advice we can give is to go to the Emmet homepage, where it will show if it is available for your editor and how to get it working.

https://emmet.io/

Alternatively, the code editors website will likely have the same information available as Emmet is widely used.

VSCode is probably the most commonly used editor right now, it comes with Emmet preinstalled but you need to update the configuration to use Emmet in jsx or tsx files.

In settings, search for Emmet and then in the `Include Languages` section add:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| javascript | javascriptreact |
| typescript | typescriptreact |